# How to find this integral $I=\int_{0}^{1} t^{-1/2}\left(1-\frac{t}{1+4y}\right)^{-1/2-ix}dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

**Question:**

> Find the closed form of
>
> $$I(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}\left(1-\dfrac{t}{1+4y}\right)^{-1/2-ix}dt$$
>
> where $i^2=-1$

I have used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D+t%5E%7B-1%2F2%7D%281-%5Cdfrac%7Bt%7D%7B1%2B4y%7D%29%5E%7B-1%2F2-ix%7Ddt) but it can't help me out. How to find it?

Thank you

---

I have explained why I can't comment, because in China we can't comment in MSE, (I don't know why?) Now, I can only post questions and I also can answer questions , but I can't comment.

china math110 also said that he can't comment. Here is the proof: [How find all positive real $\beta$ such A finite number of $\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2}\right|<\frac{\beta}{q^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915679/how-find-all-positive-real-beta-such-a-finite-number-of-left-fracpq-s)

[How prove $f(a_{i})=0$ if $\int_{0}^{1}x^kf(x)dx=0,k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916026/how-prove-fa-i-0-if-int-01xkfxdx-0-k-1-2-3-cdots-n)

Comment: Mr. @CameronWilliams, I can understand if he doesn't wanna interact with those that comment and answer china math's problem. Don't be so harsh about that ツ

Comment: *wolf can't help* - Yeah... wolves never do... :-(

Answer (score 1):

If your *x* and *y* are independent of *t*, then the answer is simply an [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).