# Specification of Hurwitz's Theorem

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

> [Hurwitz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) in Number Theory states that for every
>   irrational number $\xi$, the equation
>   $$\left|\xi-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}$$ has infinitely
>   many solutions $(p,q)$ such that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, and
>   that this is not true of
>   $$\left|\xi-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{(\sqrt{5}+\varepsilon)q^2}$$
>   has finitely many relative prime solutions for any $\varepsilon>0$.

There is a meaningful sense in which this is a statement about $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, because the proof of the second part is a property of the number $\phi$, and if $\phi$ (plus a specific set of numbers that are equivalent to $\phi$ in a certain sense), then the bound changes to $2\sqrt{2}$. We might only care about some other irrational number, and so we might form the following problem:

> Let $\mu(\xi)$ be the unique number (should it exist) that has the
>   property that  $$\left|\xi-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{\mu(\xi)q^2}$$
>   has infinitely many solutions $(p,q)$ such that $p$ and $q$ are
>   relatively prime, and that
>   $$\left|\xi-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{(\mu(\xi)+\varepsilon)q^2}$$
>   has finitely many relative prime solutions for any $\varepsilon>0$.

I am interested in when $\mu(\xi)$ exists (I conjecture that this is equivalent to asking when does $\xi$ have bounded coefficients in its continued fraction expansion), and when it does exist, how to calculate it (presumably via solving a recurrence). Proofs, references, and commentary on the current state of the problem (if it is unsolved) are all welcome.

For certain instances of the problem, I have found the value of $\mu(\xi)$ via recurrences. For example, I have proven that $\mu(\sqrt{d})=2\sqrt{d}$ for square-free $d$. I know that this is related to [Markov Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number) and the [Markov Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_spectrum), however neither of those answer my question.

This is the same problem as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915540/how-find-the-value-beta-such-left-fracpq-sqrt2-right-frac-beta) but I'm looking for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little unclear, it is very likely that, given the larger root of
$$ A x^2 + B xy + Cy^2,  $$
(root meaning either $x/y$ or $y/x$ so it becomes a function of one variable)
of discriminant
$$ \Delta = B^2 - 4AC > 0, $$
you want
$$ \sqrt \Delta $$
Notice that the discriminant of $x^2 - d y^2$ is $4d,$ and the square root of that is $2 \sqrt d.$

Comment: I edited the question which hopefully makes things clearer. 

Is this post a conjecture as to the answer of my problem? Or something else?

Comment: @StellaBiderman,  I think it is the answer. Note that the Golden Ratio solves $x^2 + xy - y^2$ of discriminant $5;$ divide through by $x^2,$ and call the ratio $r,$ we have $1 + r - r^2 = 0.$

Comment: This seems interesting, as it also satisfies the small number of other examples I have. Unfortunately, my set of solved examples is pretty small due to a heavy reliance on the continued fraction expansion.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, do me a favor, solve your problem for the larger root of $1 + 3 r - 2 r^2 = 0.$ The form $x^2 + 3 xy - 2 y^2$ is Lagrange reduced, meaning the continued fraction is purely periodic. Discriminant is $17.$

Comment: Sorry I lost Internet connection. Numerically I'm getting 4.12426, though I don't have access to a CAS right now and I wrote a program to solve it on my brother's TI-84 (ain't the holidays marvelous)

Comment: @Stella $\sqrt {17} \approx 4.123.$ Meanwhile, the continued fraction for $\frac{3 + \sqrt {17}}{4}$ is $1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3$ and so on

Comment: @StellaBiderman I think you can do it. Be aware that this is all special to "quadratic irrationals." An inexpensive modern book that covers what else is known http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions?format=PB

Answer (score 1):

Because I already think this is what you are dealing with: given a binary form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2$ with positive $\Delta = B^2 - 4 AC,$ not a square but permitted square factors.

If you have a single solution to $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 = W,$ there are infinitely many, and $|x|,|y|$ get arbitrarily large while $W$ stays fixed.

Take any of the infinitely many solutions to
$$  \tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4. $$ Create the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{\tau - B \sigma}{2} & -C \sigma \\
A \sigma & \frac{\tau + B \sigma}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Given a solution $(x,y)$ to $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 = W,$ we get infinitely many with 
$$ (x,y) \mapsto \left(\frac{\tau - B \sigma}{2} x -C \sigma y, \; \;  A \sigma x +  \frac{\tau + B \sigma}{2} y \right) $$

Oh, if we take the smallest $\sigma > 0$ in $  \tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4, $ and call the resulting matrix $M,$ then all those matrices can be written as $M^n$ for $n$ a positive or negative integer.