# Problem with inequality: $ \left| \sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{1}{3q^2}$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, diophantine-approximation

Prove that for for all $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$, $q>0$ we have:
$$
\left| \sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{1}{3q^2}.
$$

To be honest, I do not know where to start - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting that we can only get about $|\sqrt{2}-\frac ab|>\frac 1{5b^2}$ using [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence)

Comment: Sorry about the closure see-saw. I misread the question initially. Anyway, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/915580/11619) is a related answer by Winther.

Comment: @vrugtehagel, just to quibble, though maybe that's the issue, but it seems to me that I get $|p/q-\sqrt{2}|>1/(2\sqrt{2}\,q^2$ for large $q$ by following Liouville's idea...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assume that $p>0$ and $q>1$, and $\sqrt 2 + p/q ≤ 3$, otherwise this is easy: if $\sqrt 2 + p/q > 3$ then $\sqrt 2-p/q < 2\sqrt 2 - 3<0$, so $$\left|\sqrt2 - \frac{p}{q}\right| > 3-2\sqrt 2 > 1/12 ≥ 1/(3q^2)$$

The highest power of $2$ dividing $2q^2$ is odd, while the highest power of $2$ dividing $p^2$ is even. Then, $p^2$ and $2q^2$ must be distinct integers, thus $|2 q^2 - p^2| \geq 1$. Then

$$\left|\sqrt2 - \frac{p}{q}\right| = \frac{|2p^2-q^2|}{q^2(\sqrt{2}+p/q)} \ge \frac{1}{q^2(\sqrt2 + p / q)} \ge \frac{1}{3q^2},$$

as desired.

Comment: $|2q^2-p^2|\ge 1$ can also by explained by the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ (irrationality gives it nonzero, the difference between 2 integers is at least 1).

Comment: @Watson Not really sure why the inequality is trivial if $\sqrt{2}+p/q>3$.

Comment: @egreg : I hope this is clearer now. You're right, I should have written a little bit more about this part.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic number of order $2$ for it is irrational and satisfies  $f(x)=x^2-2=0$. For $x\in [\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}+1]$,  $\frac{1}{4} <f'(x)=2x<5$. Thus, by the mean value theorem
$$ |f(\sqrt{2})-f(x)|=|x^2-2|< 5|\sqrt{2}-x|$$

Claim: for any integers $p$, $q$ ($q\geq1$)
$$
\begin{align}
\big|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}\big|>\frac{1}{5q^2}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$

This clearly holds true if $|\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{p}{q}|> 1$. If $|\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{p}{q}|\leq 1$, then by $\eqref{one}$
$$
\big|f(p/q)|=\big|\tfrac{p^2}{q^2}-2|< 5|\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{p}{q}|
$$
and so
$$
q^2|f(p/q)|<5q^2|\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{p}{q}|
$$
Clearly $q^2|f(p/q)|=|p^2-2q^2|$ is a nonnegative integer. Since the equation $f(x)=x^2-2=0$ has no rational solution,  $q^2|f(p/q)|\geq1$. Putting things together,
$$
\big|\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{p}{q}\big|>\frac{1}{5q^2}
$$
for all $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $q\geq1$.

---

Comment: This solution I outlined above is an adaptation of standard technique used by Liouville to prove the following result:

**Theorem:** For any real algebraic number of degree $n>1$, there exists a positive integers $M$ such that
$$
\Big|z-\frac{p}{q}\Big|>\frac{1}{Mq^n}
$$
for all integers $p$ and $q$, $q\geq1$.