# Improving the Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Recall that Dirichlet showed the following:

> For every real number $x$ and every $Q>1$, there exists an integer vector $(p,q)\in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $|xq-p|<1/Q$ and $0<q<Q$.

I wonder if the following is true:

> For every real number $x$ and every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $Q_{\epsilon}$ such that for all $Q>Q_{\epsilon}$, there is
> an integer vector $(p,q)\in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $|xq-p|<\epsilon/Q$ and $0<q<Q$.

Of course this is trivially true when $x$ is rational, but I don't know what happens when $x$ is irrational (in particular when it is transcendental).

Note the Lerendre's theorem should be a special case of this by taking $\epsilon=1$ and we can always assume $Q>Q_{\epsilon} \ge 1$.

---

Update: As per the comments by rtybase below, by Liouville's theorem (on diophantine approximation), my statement is false if $x$ is algebraic. But what happens when $x$ is transcendental?

Comment: I thought it's [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem). Do you have any historical references pointing at Legendre?

Comment: In any case, that may not be valid for all the $x$. Specifically, [algebraic numbers of degree $2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence).

Comment: @rtybase To be safe, let me change it to Dirichlet. My source isn't very reliable... Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, you have the answer in my 2nd comment. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475708/if-m-and-n-are-integers-show-that-left-sqrt3-fracmn-right-ge-f/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229966/how-to-prove-left-sqrt2-fracmn-right-frac13n2-inductively) are a few specific examples.

Comment: Yes, thanks! But now I am also curious about the transcendental case...Just updated my question. @rtybase

Comment: Look up "Badly approximable numbers"; basically this property you describe has to do with whether or not the partial quotients of the continued fraction expansion are bounded

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is false. The best possible constant is $\epsilon = \frac 1 {\sqrt 5}$, which is tight for $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ and its equivalent numbers under the equivalence relation:

$$y\sim x \iff y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}; ad-bc=1$$

You can prove that by showing that the best approximants are the convergents to the continued fraction, then noting that those for $\phi$ are ratios of Fibonacci numbers. Then proving that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n|\phi F_n-F_{n+1}|\to \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$$

Using the closed form for Fibonacci numbers.

If you exclude all the $x\sim\phi$ you can improve the constant to $\epsilon=2\sqrt 2$, and if you repeat the process you find the [Lagrange numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_number), which converge to 3.

As noted in the comments, the irrationality measure of all irrational algebraic numbers is 2 (Roth's theorem). As for transcendental numbers, almost all of them have irrationality measure 2 still.

Comment: The way the question is asked is ... tricky. For example OP asks for "there is an integer vector", i.e. one or more. The $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ from [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) is of the style "there are infinitely many", over that value it is still possible for "there exist only finitely many", which fits the "there is an integer vector" criteria.

Comment: @rtybase they asked for an integer vector for every $Q>1$. You're right that I was a bit sloppy in establishing that my results hold with the $<1/Q$, as I substituted for $1/q$ which is weaker, but they're nearly equivalent. Another thing that can be problematic is if Q isn't an integer and an inequality that holds for $\lfloor Q\rfloor$ might not hold for Q.