# Approximating multiples of reals with integers

Tags: real-analysis

I have recently recalled a problem from my school days, where I was asked if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist positive integers $m, n$ such that $|m\sqrt 2 - n|< \varepsilon$. I have just realized, that I do not really know of a simple way to solve this problem. Furthermore, would be good if that solution could be applied also to any $q\in \Bbb R_+$ instead of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Like $\{m\sqrt{2}\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$?

Comment: Well, the equivalent to the OP is that it is dense at $\{0\}$ @AlexeyBurdin

Comment: Well, $m=n=0$ is always a solution.

Comment: thanks @enzotib, I've added the (strict) positivity condition explicilty

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)

Comment: Even easier with [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Comment: There is also [Liouville's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence) for lower bounds for algebraic numbers. One example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229966/how-to-prove-left-sqrt2-fracmn-right-frac13n2-inductively).

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<q\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, $M=\{mq-n:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $a=\inf\{x:x\in M\land x>0\}$.
Assume on contrary $a>0$.

If $a\in M$, then for every $0<x\in M$ we have $0\leq x-\lfloor x/a\rfloor a<a$ and since $x-\lfloor x/a\rfloor a\in M$ this implies $x=\lfloor x/a\rfloor a\in a\Bbb Z$.
Then $q=au$ and $1=av$ for some $u,v\in\Bbb Z$, and we get the contradiction $q=u/v\in\Bbb Q$.

If $a\notin M$, by definition of infimum, then there exists $m',n'\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a<m'q-n'\lt 2a$ and, again by definition of infimum, there exists $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a<mq-n\lt m'q-n'$.
Then $0\lt(m'-m)q-(n'-n)\lt a$ - a contradiction.

Comment: It might be worth explaining why there exist such $m,m'.n.n'$ in the last paragraph? (The pigeonhole principle argument is certainly the standard way of handling this; I just haven't seen it phrased quite this way before.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I add an explanation in the answer.